# How to unpublish nodes which are missing in migration source?

Tags: 8, migrations

I have a CSV file with two rows. I executed the migration and two nodes are imported.

Now I deleted one row from the CSV and execute the migration again.

I now want to unpublish the node which is missing in the CSV.

Is it possible? How will I do that?

Comment: did you try `drush mim MIGRATION_NAME --update` ?

Comment: I am not using drush for migration. My migration executes on form submission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used an EventSubscriber for this. Here is my code.

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
  $events = [];
  $events[MigrateEvents::PRE_IMPORT][] = ['archiveMissingNodes'];
  return $events;
}

/**
 * Archives the missing contact persons.
 *
 * @param \Drupal\migrate\Event\MigrateImportEvent $event
 *   The migration import event.
 *
 * @throws \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException
 */
public function archiveMissingNodes(MigrateImportEvent $event) {
  $migration = $event->getMigration();

  if ($migration->id() === 'my_migration_id') {
    $id_map = $migration->getIdMap();
    $id_map->prepareUpdate();

    // Clone so that any generators aren't initialized prematurely.
    $source = clone $migration->getSourcePlugin();
    $source->rewind();
    $source_id_values = [];

    while ($source->valid()) {
      $source_id_values[] = $source->current()->getSourceIdValues();
      $source->next();
    }
    $id_map->rewind();

    while ($id_map->valid()) {
      $map_source_id = $id_map->currentSource();

      $destination_ids = $id_map->currentDestination();

      if (!empty($destination_ids['nid'])) {
        $node = $this->nodeStorage->load($destination_ids['nid']);

        if ($node instanceof NodeInterface) {
          if (!in_array($map_source_id, $source_id_values, TRUE) && $node->get('moderation_state')->getString() !== 'archived') {
            $node->setNewRevision(TRUE);
            $node->set('moderation_state', 'archived');
            $node->set('revision_log', '');
            $node->setRevisionCreationTime($this->time->getRequestTime());
            $node->setRevisionUserId($this->currentUser->id());
            $node->setRevisionTranslationAffected(TRUE);
            $node->save();
          }
        }
      }

      $id_map->next();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't seem to work when the source plugin uses `yield` to create the generator.

Comment: The code is similar to https://git.drupalcode.org/project/migrate_tools/-/blob/0813c0fb91406695b4dd37e49f67e56ed26b7bbd/src/EventSubscriber/MigrationImportSync.php#L48 except the $node->set/$node->save. I am not sure that $id_map->prepareUpdate(); is necessary here, as this will mark all the nodes in the map for update, that might not be intended and seems not necessary to accomplish OPs goal.

Comment: $id_map->prepareUpdate() is necessary for the solution given, but it marks all the nodes for update as well. If you do not like this, you can find a solution here https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_tools/issues/3104105

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps

1. modify your migration code
2. first of all - run a select query to fetch all the nids of that content type or bundle for which you are migrating the data
3. next, run migration
4. identify the nodes which are not part of migration but exist in your select query
5. in while loop, load these nodes
6. mark them as unpublished
7. save these nodes

done!